# Unknown dictionary layout type: direct

Tags: sql, database, dictionary, clickhouse

I am trying to create a dictionary with a direct layout in Clickhouse, it sends me the following error when I try to do so:

> Code: 137. DB::Exception: Received from clickhouse-server:9000. DB::Exception: Unknown dictionary layout type: direct.

My query looks like this:

```sql
 CREATE DICTIONARY IF NOT EXISTS default.dict
(
  -- attributes here
)
PRIMARY KEY `ID`
SOURCE(CLICKHOUSE(
    host 'localhost'
    port 9000
    user 'default'
    password ''
    db 'default'
    table 'default.test1'
))
LAYOUT(DIRECT())
LIFETIME(300)
```

Do you know where it comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not released yet. Try the last testing https://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/deb/testing/main/